# Segmentation fault on printing pointer value

Tags: c

The following program crashes when I try to print the value of `v`. I'm trying to understand why. Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int v[5000000];
    printf("\n\nv = %p", v);
     return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: the program does not segfault if instead of allocating 5000000 elements I allocate 500000 or less.

**EDIT(2)**: increasing the stack size solved the problem. On Linux, I increase the stack size after reading the answer of stephane-rouberol (using `ulimit -s <some_large_number>`).

Comment: Why are you trying to print *"Indeterminate"* elements of an Uninitialized array?

Comment: I'm trying to print the pointer value. Isn't `v` a pointer to an array of `int`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congrats, you have *stack overflow* :)

Find a way to increase the size of the stack or just allocate the array dynamically:

```
int* v = malloc( 5000000 * sizeof *v);

/* do something */

free( v );
```

Comment: So an array `v[10000]` is stored on the stack? But then why does the program crash on the printing step? Also, how do I increase the stack size?

Comment: @curvature - it depends on your compiler. You should read it's manual.

Comment: @Als - doesn't `%p` means - print the _address_, not the content pointed by?

Comment: In addition he seems to have a rather crappy compiler/linker that doesn't know how large the stack is for a process of the targetted platform. I would expect the linker to know that at least on desktop OS compilers. In Windows for example, I believe you can get this info by a simple API call GetSystemInfo().

Comment: @Lundin: the maximum stack size can be changed by the user (see my second edit on the post), so I'm not surprised the compiler (`gcc` in my case) does not know the maximum allowed stack size for the program it's compiling.

Comment: @curvature Then there should be a way to tell the linker how large the stack is. It might be the user's responsibility to keep track of the stack size, but good linkers should have a way of telling them how large it is. At least that's how it works on embedded systems, perhaps desktop system compilers are different.

Comment: @Lundin - interesting, I didn't know the way embedded systems work. But I have some experience with Visual Studio (Windows) and gcc (RHEL, Ubuntu) and none of them have this kind of knowledge. And they are not "crappy" compilers.

Comment: @KirilKirov Why do you consider a compiler/linker that silently accepts stack overflow as good? Or maybe every desktop developer takes notes of the stack pointer, on the side as they program? "Here I declared an int, push 4. And here I left the function, pop 4."  Seems a bit tedious to me.

Comment: @Lundin - I haven't said that. I only say, that the VS and GCC do not work this way and are one of the best and widely used compilers (one - for Windows, one - for Linux). _Maybe_ the only better compiler is `intel`'s.

Answer (score 1):

Stack overflow !
See `ulimit -s` if you use `bash` or `limit stacksize` if `[t]csh`

Or instead of using stack, you can use the heap with `malloc`

Answer (score 0):

You already have the cause. `5000000` is too big to handle for the program stack where `v` will be allocated. You should allocate it dynamically with `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

The stack size of a program is dependent on compiler switches and defaults are different from OS to OS. In your case it sounds as if the stack is too small to accomodate that large number. See your compiler(linker) switches to increase stack size.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
printf("\n\nv = %p", (void *)v);
```

Comment: That didn't work. The program segfaults in the same way (which makes sense from the other answers).

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, stack overflow. To understand why and when the code actually crashes, this is what goes on between the lines:

- Try to allocate 5000000 * sizeof(int) on the stack. Let's assume this is 20MB.
- The compiler (as opposed to the linker) most likely doesn't know how large the stack is, so it merrily assumes that 20MB of the stack are taken.
- When calling printf(), the pointer address is passed on the stack to the function. The compiler will try to push this pointer address (4 bytes) at stack location 0 + 20000004. This is outside valid memory and here the program will crash.
- Had the compiler used another calling convention for printf(), for example by passing the pointer address in a CPU register instead, the program wouldn't have crashed, not until you actually tried to read/write from that huge array.